# How to use sql server database in preview mode?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As we know in Oracle no data or action query is committed until we call a commit. I want such implementation with SQL Server that I can run action queries on db but data is not changed permanently, it just let me see data before and after my action queries.

Or is there any way to mirror database on same server in such a way that I can test my queries on secondary database but it didn't have any impact on primary database.

Comment: `begin transaction` and `commit transaction`

Comment: Depends on your SQL client. Just turn off auto-commit there and you have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187807.aspx) setting to achieve a similar function to what Oracle does:

> Transactions that are automatically opened as the result of this setting being `ON` must be explicitly committed or rolled back by the user at the end of the transaction. Otherwise, the transaction and all of the data changes it contains are rolled back when the user disconnects.

You can, if you so choose, change a setting in Management Studio so that this setting is always in force when you open new query windows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it within same query window, in which you have written 'begin tran' 
do not commit until not conform.

you can execute number of query within same window, which was give you your query preview before committing transaction.

It's only possible within same query window. you can not able view preview in other query window.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Isolation level from Read Committed to Snapshot to work around with your     test queries.(If you dont want to see change in data during your transaction)

Please refer the below link for Snapshot Isolation level:

http://gavindraper.com/2012/02/18/sql-server-isolation-levels-by-example/

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question. As long as the OP doesn't _start_ a transaction in SQL server (by keeping the default auto-commit mode), the isolation level does not come into play.